# Different recyclerview in different fragment can use same Recyclerview adapter class ? It is good approach? Why?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

In my main activity have 3 fragments in bottom navigation.

Assume `fragment1`, `fragment2`, `fragment3`.

fragment1 & 2 have `recyclerview` both need to list same content but different records.
Now adapter name is `recordAdapter` is the class.
I am using same adapter class in both `recylerview`. 
It is right or wrong?
Then Why?

Ex : 
I planned to show India and Australia Football team players list name and images in `recyclerview`. `fragment1` for India and `fragment2` for Australia.

In 
`fragment1` and `fragment2` can use same adapter class for both.
or use separate adapter class for each fragments.

Comment: Yes you can go with the same adapter for both recycler view  and can populate a different set of records on the basis of called by

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use same adapter class for those recycler views. Since, adapter will define the UI and bind data to it based on the arguments it pass. So you will pass different data on both the cases, it will create same UI but with diff data.
(Code Reusability).

But if you want extremely different UI in both the cases, you can opt different adapter class.

Answer (score -1):

ye You can use as you mention...but if you have same UI in all the fragments where you want to use same adapter.